# executing loops in Beanshell interpreter

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a string, srcCode, that contains

```
"HashSet hs = new HashSet();
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<10,i=i+2){
    hs.add(i);
    }"
```

using BeanShell interpret, am trying to interpret it, below is the code:

```
bsh.set("hs", hs);
bsh.eval("import java.lang.String;");
bsh.eval(srcCode);
```

its giving me error, "line 2 column 11 encountered EOF"
Can that be acheived using the BeanShell interpreter?

Answer (score 1):

fix for loop syntax, you are missing `;`

```
for(i=0; i<10; i = i + 2) {
```

Comment: Oh yes i just did that but its still giving me the same error,
"line 2 column 11,encoutered EOF"